# C# console key press event

Tags: c#, console-application, keyevent

I just started to learn c# console events.

Is there a possible way that a c# application will automatically jump into a new command by just pressing a letter.

I have this mini code below.

I was developing a mini text base base.

I just used the Console.Read();
so the user will type the letter Y then he still needs to press the enter key
what I wanted is, if the user will press "y" or anykey into the keyboard the statement goes to the if statement.

Is it possible.

```
        Console.Write("Press Y to start the game.");

        char theKey = (char) Console.Read();


        if (theKey == 'y' || theKey == 'Y')
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Hello");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Error");
```

Comment: Your code example already shows you using `ReadKey()`, so you obviously know about that method. Why aren't you just using that for the input of the character `Y` as well? It's not very clear why you are asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ReadKey` method ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
Console.Write("Press Y to start the game.");

char theKey = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

if (theKey == 'y' || theKey == 'Y')
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Hello");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
    Console.Write("Error");
```

The return value of `ReadKey` method is `ConsoleKey` enum so you can use it in the if condition:

```
Console.Write("Press Y to start the game.");

ConsoleKey consoleKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;

if (consoleKey == ConsoleKey.Y)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Hello");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
    Console.Write("Error");
```

Comment: Casting the `Key` property is incorrect. The correct way to interpret the result would be either to simply compare the `Key` value with the `ConsoleKey.Y` enum value, or to retrieve the `KeyChar` property value instead (which _is_ a `char` value and can be compared to `y` and `Y`). I prefer using `ConsoleKey.Y` because that handles the casing issue (i.e. because it's the `Y` _key_, and not the `y` or `Y` _character_)

Comment: @PeterDuniho btw. where should I insert the line ConsoleKey.Y that you're referring to? I am not very good at console programming still starting to learn.

Comment: @kmatyaszek ohh I see. what If i dont use the letter Y. what if i use random keys.

Comment: @ScapeGoat you can use any value from `ConsoleKey` enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.consolekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @kmatyaszek       if (consoleKey == ConsoleKey.) how about a random character from the keyboard?

Comment: Your first code example is still wrong. Casting the `Key` property to `char` value is simply incorrect. To get the `char` value for the input, use `KeyChar`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i already change it to : ConsoleKey consoleKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;

Comment: @kmatyaszek theres a lot of them. i mean randomly. consoleKey == ConsoleKey.Y    .Y change to?

Comment: @ScapeGoat why you need randomly key and what will you do with this key?

Comment: @kmatyaszek . just a random key to jump in the if statement. what i did is this if (consoleKey == consoleKey)